# Execute raw graphQL query using OkHttp Client

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client

I have a graphQL query that I want to execute it as raw request and don't want to depend on any clients to execute this request (I don't want to use apollo client for android to execute it)

I have created the string that forms this query and tries to make this request using OkHttp client but I think there is something missing because of every time I send the request the respond is internal server error. But if I execute this query using apollo-client for android it returns with a response.

Here is my try for executing the raw query request using OkHttp:

```
val requestBodyString = "  cities{\n" +
            "    name\n" +
            "  }"

fun makeRequest(url: String): Response{
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val requestBody = RequestBody.create(null, requestBodyString)
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestBody)
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/graphql").build()
        return client.newCall(request).execute()
    }
```

I follow [yelp documentation](https://www.yelp.com/developers/graphql/guides/requests) for making requests but it doesn't work for me. and I can't figure why?

Answer (score 2):

Try to send as a JSON

```
    val query = "  cities{\n" +
            "    name\n" +
            "  }"

   fun makeRequest(url: String): Response{
            val client = OkHttpClient()

           val json = JSONObject()
           json.put("query",query)

            val requestBody = RequestBody.create(null, json.toString())
            val request = Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestBody)
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json").build()
            return client.newCall(request).execute()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was recently experimenting with something similar. The solution I came up with was to hit the URL with an encoded query param.

`String url = url + "query?" + URLEncoder.encode(query);`

I've had success using OkHttp, but I've noticed some other clients aren't able to communicate with GraphQl.

Edit: For what it's worth, the URL I used was not secured (http), and the only header I set was for basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use the OKHttp Client using the following code-snippet, its fairly simple and strainght forward. Below is the Java Code but i guess the corresponding Kotlin code would also be straight forward.

```
String response = "";
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    String json ="query LaunchDetails($id:ID!) {\n" +
            "    launch(id: $id) {\n" +
            "        id\n" +
            "        site\n" +
            "        mission {\n" +
            "            name\n" +
            "            missionPatch(size:LARGE)\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    jsonObject.put("query",json);
    JSONObject variables = new JSONObject();
    variables.put("id", 89);
    jsonObject.put("variables",variables);

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(jsonObject.toString(), MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://apollo-fullstack-tutorial.herokuapp.com/graphql")
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();

    response = client.newCall(request).execute().body().string();
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    System.out.println(ioException.toString());
}
```

Note the use of **.string()** instead of **.toString()** while storing the response Json in the response object.